# Using jquery to dynamically load Vimeo videos

Tags: jquery, vimeo

I would like to create a function that would allow me to embed my Vimeo videos on my website and run it like a YouTube playlist i.e. when a video link is clicked, rather than reloading the page it only reloads the video. So for example, this being a film website, I have a trailer for the project as well as a few promo clips, I would like to be able to show all of those by simply having the user click a link which loads a new video. How would I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

this should work too.

```
$('#some_video_container').html('<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/12345?
                                 title=1&amp;byline=1&amp;portrait=1" width="643"
                                 height="360" frameborder="0"></iframe>');
```

Answer (score 5):

Here you go.

```
$.getJSON('http://www.vimeo.com/api/oembed.json?url=' + encodeURIComponent('http://vimeo.com/7100569') + '&width=300&callback=?', function(data){
        $('#some_video_container').html(data.html);
});
```

Comment: i like this solution better

Comment: Cool. Any idea how to do this over https?

Comment: This is kind of old, so I would use [jQuery's $.ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) now. To load over https, just omit the protocol from the url, like so: $.ajax('//www.vimeo.com/api... **note the lack of http or https, the browser will figure this out. Just start the url with slash slash**

Answer (score 1):

Checkout [oembed](http://oembed.com). The best provider I know of is http://embed.ly

The official JQuery Embed.ly plugin is here: https://github.com/embedly/embedly-jquery

Answer (score 0):

I've also used Vimeo Playlist, found here: http://luwes.co/labs/vimeo-playlist/

You can set where you want the playlist list (on top, bottom or side of the video). Overall it's pretty easy to set up. You just put your video urls in an array in the script:

```
<div id="player"></div>
<script src="http://luwes.co/vimeowrap.js/vimeowrap.js"></script>
<script src="http://luwes.co/vimeowrap.js/vimeowrap.playlist.js"></script>
<script>
    vimeowrap('player').setup({
        urls: [
            'https://vimeo.com/user3709818',
            'https://vimeo.com/user3709818'
        ],
        plugins: {
            'playlist':{}
        }
    });
</script>
```