# Extract thumbs from Vimeo urls

Tags: c#, .net, regex, parsing, vimeo

I want to extract images from Vimeo videos pages. I have already gone through these links

[C# regex to get video id from youtube and vimeo by url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652046/c-sharp-regex-to-get-video-id-from-youtube-and-vimeo-by-url)

[Get img thumbnails from Vimeo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361149/get-img-thumbnails-from-vimeo)

[Using jquery to dynamically load Vimeo videos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6805297/using-jquery-to-dynamically-load-vimeo-videos)

and with the help of above links I am upto this regex: **vimeo.com/(?:.*#|.*/videos/)?([0-9]+)**

I am able to resolve video id (which I need to extract thumbnails) via above regex for these urls

http://vimeo.com/channels/hd#11384488

http://vimeo.com/groups/brooklynbands/videos/7906210

http://vimeo.com/staffpicks#13561592

http://vimeo.com/834881

but I am not able to get id for these type of urls:

http://vimeo.com/videoschool/lesson/20/make-a-great-holiday-video

http://vimeo.com/videoschool/lesson/38/video-101-adding-text-and-titles-with-imovie

**These urls don't even contain the video id information**. How can I extract video id from this? Is there any other way by which I can extract thumbnails of vimeo video by providing url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to crawl the URL and parse the video id from the HTML. It's in there a bunch of times, but one way would be to grab it from the id of one of the `<div>` tags that surrounds the video. For that last URL you posted it looks like this:

`<div id="player_17861379_1698442974" class="f player">`

The first string of numbers between underscore characters is the video id. You can parse it from the HTML with a regex like:

`<div[^<]+?id="player_(\d+?)_`

Which should give you 17861379. This same video without the article is at http://vimeo.com/17861379.